# On intersection of null geodesics

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lorentzian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let us consider a globally hyperbolic Lorentzian manifold $(M,g)$ with empty cut locus. Suppose that
$p$ is a point in $M$ and consider $C^-(p)$ to be the past null cone in $M$ emanating from the point $p$. Next, suppose that $q_1,q_2 \in C^-(p)$ and denote by $\gamma_{q_1}$ and $\gamma_{q_2}$ the null geodesics that emanate from $q_1$ and $q_2$ respectively in the direction of the null vector that is normal to the null cone there.

Is it true that $\gamma_{q_1}$ and $\gamma_{q_2}$ can never intersect in $M\setminus C^-(p)$?

Comment: I should clarify that of course. Here, due to splitting of spacetime, you can always associate to a null vector $v=c\partial_t+\nu$ a canonical dual null vector $\tilde{v}=-c\partial_t+\nu$. The vector $\tilde{v}$ is what I mean by the (pseudo)-normal.

Comment: wait, I thought I understood your question, but now I am confused. Are $\gamma_{q_1}$ and $\gamma_{q_2}$ supposed to be transverse to $C^-(p)$ or not? The way the question text itself is written, I would've interpreted $\gamma_{q_1}$ as the null geodesic joining $p$ to $q_1$. But your comment suggest something else.

Comment: In fact, I don't understand your comment at all! Given a $C^-(p)$ the only way I know where you can construct a "dual null vector" for $q\in C^-(p)$ is if you prescribe a priori a space-like foliation of $C^-(p)$, whereby there is a canonical null direction transverse to $C^-(p)$ that is orthogonal to the space-like leave through $q$. But this is not as simple as what you claimed in your comment.

Comment: Yes, the geodesics should be transverse to the cone. I think this is all well-defined by global hyperbolicity, since spacetime has a global splitting of the form $g(t,x)= -\beta(t,x) dt^2+ g_0(t,x)$.

Comment: The splitting is not canonical, there are many such splittings, so it seems that the transverse geodesics that you are considering are ill defined unless you introduce a privileged timelike vector field.

Comment: As Ettore Minguzzi pointed out in the previous comment, the set-up is ill-defined and the question unanswerable. Since the OP has not provided additional clarification, I am voting to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

The geodesic from $p$ to $q_i$ is normal to $C^-(p)$ at $q_i$.
So essentially you ask if two null geodesics from $p$ intersect in $C^-(p)$.
Since the cut locus is empty, the answer is no.

Comment: Any comment about negative vote?

Comment: Your answer is posted two years after [the OP's clarifying comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/384233/on-intersection-of-null-geodesics/461280#comment978429_384233), in which it was clearly stated that the intention is for geodesics transverse to the cone, not the geodesics tangent to the cone. So it doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: As posed by the OP (including even the clarifying comment) the question is unanswerable, since [the initial setup is ill-defined](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/384233/on-intersection-of-null-geodesics/461280#comment978807_384233).

Comment: @WillieWong The null vector that is normal to the null cone is tangent to it (the metric is not Riemannian).

Comment: Yes, ***I*** am aware that's how it actually works. But the OP is evidently confused, if you look at the comment thread below the question.

Comment: @WillieWong, you are right, still the question is formulated differently and it is better to write an answer (now it is removed from "unanswered questions").